# mysql error which causing data loss frequently

Tags: php, mysql

The error i'm getting is:

> mysql/innodb_table_space admin/facdetails uses space ID: 2 at
>   filepath: \admin\facdetails.ibd.cannot open tablespace(........) which
>   uses id:2 at filepath:.\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
>                      Error: could not open single-table tablespace file \mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd

I have seen the below proc. to ssolve the error,but it worked only for one time,after restarting it again throwing the same.

```
exit Xampp server
go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
delete the ibdata1 file
restart xampp server
```

I have got this error continously whennever i restart mysql,all my data in database is losing,when i perform above proc.

i'm working in xampp server ,and i need an early reply.

Comment: This question is more suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just go to phpMyAdmin, choose the database and change the rights.

If you can't change permissions from phpMyAdmin, try as below

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@'%' identified by 'mypasswd';
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@localhost identified by 'mypasswd';
```

% seems to not cover socket communications, that the localhost is for. WITH GRANT OPTION is only good for the super user, otherwise it is usually a security risk.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,we have granted all the permissions.I think it is related to some other problem,can you give us another explanation